# C#: Looping Through a Directory Calling an External Process

Tags: c#, xml, command-line-arguments, saxon, xquery

I have the C# code below, used to input each file in a directory, run an XQuery process on it, and output each file as an XML file. The code calls the SAXON XQuery processor. Note: the code works now but it only processes the first file in the directory. The second, third, etc. output files from the input directory come back as empty XML files. Question: how do I modify the code to process all the files (not just the first one) in the input directory?

```
  public void OpenWithArguments(string t)
  {

    string sourceDir = t;
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);

    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)

      {

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6\bin\java";


        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfoArguments = 
          @" -cp C:\mydir\saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -o:C:\myOutPutFiles\" + 
              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + 
          @".xml C:\myQueries\myquery.xquery input=" + 
              Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);

        process.Start();
        process.Close();

      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you check how many files exist in the `fileEntries` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding process.WaitForExit() after you start it.

Comment: I think that I figured out the problem. I didn't have the path for the input files set up right in the XQuery script itself. Thanks for the replies.